# Is it possible to use react material ui in auleria framework?

Tags: reactjs, aurelia, material-ui, materialize

My requirement is to use auleria framework for controller/model(get data from back end/routing/ logic's ) and react for data binding(view's). In this case, i got example to use auleria-react [git link](https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-react-example)
Here, i need to use material ui for styling. I need to know is it possible to use like this.Also some other ideas appreciated. 
Note : Am new to all above techs.

Comment: I'm pretty much trying to do the exact same thing as you.  Any luck so far?

Comment: Nope and am stick with other tasks, have to check by next week.  Also, pl share if u find any.@A2345sooted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Here are some links.

- http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/how-to-use-react-js-in-aurelia/
- https://github.com/bryanrsmith/aurelia-react-loader
- https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize

Comment: I'm trying to do this also and having lots of trouble.  I tried to retrofit react into my existing aurelia project with no luck based on links your provided.  I then tried to augment the sample aurelia-react project from the first link you provided with material-ui, again, with no luck as I can't figure out to properly import the material-ui components.  Does anybody else have this working?